# Docker build log location

Tags: bash, docker, shell, visual-studio-code, logging

I would like to know if there is a default location where docker saves all build log outputs or if it is just printing that to std out and I need to pipe it to a file myself.

I am also interested to know VS Code dev containers store those log somewhere (I know it is shown if the build fails).

Answer (score 0):

I think it does not store logs.

When I need them I issue the following command:

```bash
docker build <... COMMAND LINE ...> 2>&1 | tee <LOG_FILE_NAME>
```